# unable to refer to java web service to android

Tags: android, web-services

This is my android activity.
   Please help me out. I will send the project completely if you can drop your mail id.

```
package prakash.ws.connectsql;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String Soap_Action="http://testws.ws.prakash/testws";
private static final String Method_Name="testws";
private static final String Name_Space="http://testws.ws.prakash/";
private static final String URI="http://localhost:8045/testws/services/Testws?wsdl";
EditText ET;
TextView Tv;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Packeting the request
    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(Name_Space,Method_Name);
    // pass the parameters to the method.If it has one
    request.addProperty("name", ET.getText().toString());

    //passing the entire request to the envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope=new            SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    //transporting envelope
    AndroidHttpTransport aht=new AndroidHttpTransport(URI);
    try{
        aht.call(Soap_Action, soapEnvelope);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SoapPrimitive resultString=(SoapPrimitive)       soapEnvelope.getResult();
        Tv.setText(resultString.toString());
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Tv.setText("error");
    }       
}
}
```

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
  <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"         xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://testws.ws.prakash"      xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"       xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://testws.ws.prakash">
 <wsdl:documentation>Please Type your service description here</wsdl:documentation>
 <wsdl:types>
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"       targetNamespace="http://testws.ws.prakash">
<xs:element name="testws">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="testwsResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="testwsRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:testws"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="testwsResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:testwsResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="TestwsPortType">
  <wsdl:operation name="testws">
   <wsdl:input message="ns:testwsRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:testws"/>
   <wsdl:output message="ns:testwsResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:testwsResponse"/>
   </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="TestwsSoap11Binding" type="ns:TestwsPortType">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="testws">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:testws" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="TestwsSoap12Binding" type="ns:TestwsPortType">
  <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="testws">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:testws" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
  <soap12:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
  <soap12:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:binding name="TestwsHttpBinding" type="ns:TestwsPortType">
 <http:binding verb="POST"/>
 <wsdl:operation name="testws">
 <http:operation location="testws"/>
  <wsdl:input>
 <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
 </wsdl:input>
 <wsdl:output>
 <mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/>
 </wsdl:output>
 </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:service name="Testws">
 <wsdl:port name="TestwsHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:TestwsSoap11Binding">
 <soap:address   location="http://localhost:8045/testws/services/Testws.TestwsHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
 </wsdl:port>
 <wsdl:port name="TestwsHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:TestwsSoap12Binding">
 <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8045/testws/services/Testws.TestwsHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
  </wsdl:port>
  <wsdl:port name="TestwsHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:TestwsHttpBinding">
  <http:address location="http://localhost:8045/testws/services/Testws.TestwsHttpEndpoint/"/>
 </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
 </wsdl:definitions>
```

this web service is running fine in the server.

Manifest File

I have added the internet Permission.

Now this is the error in the logcat.

```
07-04 21:31:00.757: E/dalvikvm(375): Could not find class   'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method    prakash.ws.connectsql.MainActivity.onCreate
 07-04 21:31:00.757: W/dalvikvm(375): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 481    (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lprakash/ws/connectsql/MainActivity;
 07-04 21:31:00.757: D/dalvikvm(375): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
 07-04 21:31:00.757: D/dalvikvm(375): VFY: dead code 0x000a-004e in   Lprakash/ws/connectsql/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
 07-04 21:31:00.937: D/AndroidRuntime(375): Shutting down VM
 07-04 21:31:00.937: W/dalvikvm(375): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at prakash.ws.connectsql.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-04 21:31:00.957: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-04 21:31:05.307: I/Process(375): Sending signal. PID: 375 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Have you specified the build paths for the ksoap library ???